# Mi código funciona bien en unos navegadores pero en otros no

Tags: javascript, css, archivo, flask, navegador-web

Actualmente estoy desarrollando una app web hecha en flask, resulta que le añadí unos formularios que se muestran al presionar un botón en la misma pagina con js, este les añade una clase al ser presionado para poder verlos y rellenarlos, el problema es que en el navegador de opera al presionar los botones solo logra reaccionar el primer formulario y cuando presiono los otros botones no muestra nada, probé con edge y firefox y este problema no se da, después probé con chrome y también lo logro, pero al borrarle las cookies y datos de navegación sucedió lo mismo que con opera, probé lo de borrar las cookies y datos en edge y firefox y todo seguía bien, también probé abrir un archivo html con los scripts y estilos que necesitaban los formularios y abrí el archivo sin necesidad de el servidor (flask) en opera y al presionar los botones todo funciono correctamente, elimine por un momento todos los scripts y estilos que no necesitaban los formularios en el servidor pero siguió con el mismo problema, el problema no esta en el servidor ya que este solo influye en la recolección de los datos de los formularios, por favor ayuda.[image: formularios]

js para mostrar formulario(tengo 3 archivos con lo mismo pero diferentes clases y ids para cada formulario):

````
var btnAbrirPopup = document.getElementById('btn-abrir-popup'),
    overlay = document.getElementById('overlay'),
    popup = document.getElementById('popup'),
    btnCerrarPopup = document.getElementById('btn-cerrar-popup');

btnAbrirPopup.addEventListener('click', function() {
    overlay.classList.add('active');
    popup.classList.add('active');
});
btnCerrarPopup.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    overlay.classList.remove('active');
    popup.classList.remove('active');
});```
````

Answer (score 0):

Descubrí el error, el error tiene que ver con el bloqueador de anuncios, tenia una carpeta llamada "popups" donde contengo todos los scripts para abrir los formularios, el bloqueador de anuncios detecta tal palabra y la bloquea por lo cual no cargaban los otros scripts, estuve todo 1 día tratando de resolverlo ;C, pero es muy gratificante ver el problema resuelto.